# Doubt in given hint's interpretation for a question.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is : Given $a,b$ as two odd integers, show $a^2+b^2$ is not a square number.

Book's hint states that any odd integer can be of the form: $n = 3q +r$, hence the $3$ cases based on value of $r$ are :
 (i) if $r=0, n_1 = 3q \implies  3\mid n_1$
(ii) if $r=1, n_2 = 3q+1\implies   3\mid (2n_2+1)$
(iii) if $r=2, n_3 = 3q+2\implies   3\mid (n_3+1)$

I feel that the book's approach is to find all $6$ possible combinations, with the sum of individual squares as $m_i$ as :
(a) $m_1=n_1^2+n_1^2$
(b) $m_2=n_2^2+n_2^2$
(c) $m_3=n_3^2+n_3^2$
(d) $m_4=n_1^2+n_2^2$
(e) $m_5=n_1^2+n_3^2$
(f) $m_6=n_2^2+n_3^2$

I am doubtful about the interpretation made, hence want to confirm.

Comment: But any integer, not only odd integers, can be of the form $n = 3q +r$

Comment: Hint:  if $n$ is odd then $n^2\equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar This is correct. But, the definite criteria can be not in terms of any residue class for any integer $n$. However, for square of any odd number $n$ can state as, $n^2=(2k+1)^2 = 8k'+1$. So, if IGNORE the book's approach, then two numbers of the $8k'+1$ form will never lead to a square as have residue as $2$ wrt $8$. But, the book's hint seems aimless then, or can-not understand it.

Comment: @jiten What happens after dividing into 6 combinations from the book's approach?

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar  First, I want to edit my earlier comment by modifying the second line as : "...in terms of any residue class, except $2$, for any integer $n$." The $6$ combinations are my imagination. The book stops at stating the $3$ classes in terms of conditions for divisibility wrt $3$.

Comment: I suspect the book's hint is useless. Looking at it modulo $3$ shows that one of $a$ and $b$ must be divisible by $3$, but there's no obvious way from there onwards. Looking at the matter modulo $4$ gives a short and obvious proof.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar I want to ask why it is that for any odd integer, there cannot be any criteria except division by 2. Why any criteria by division by $3$ will fail as : $3n+1$ will fail for $16$, $3n+2$ will fail for $14$. Only the residue class wrt $2$ is a success. Can there be a formal reason/proof  for that. Also, why it is that square of odd integer will satisfy the residue criteria wrt 4/8.

Comment: When any number can be in the form of $3q+r$ and nowhere it provided integers to be odd, I also suspect this is not a hint.

Comment: Because odd number $+ 1 =$ even number, and $3q$ depending on $q$ can both be odd or even.

Comment: For your last question: $c^2=a^2 + b^2$ is congruent to $2 ($mode $4)$ and this shows $c$ should have a $\sqrt 2$ factor and that is impossible as it should be an integer. @jiten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can it confirm as so:

Any odd square is congruent to $1 (\mod 4)$.

Then, what will the sum of two odd squares be? And what conclusion can you arrive at?

Comment: Please help in understanding the given hint of book.

Comment: @jiten I think the book is trying to do proof by cases, to eliminate all possible solutions, which ultimately disproves that $a^2+b^2$ cannot be a perfect square.

Comment: So, my interpretation is correct then.

Comment: @jiten Yes! You are correct.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Use congruence $\bmod 4$ and $(2k+1)^2=4k^2+4k+1$.